# Does Ubuntu 16.04 LTS have Blue Ray Support?

Tags: 16.04, burning, blu-ray

I read some time ago that Ubuntu doesn't support the burning of Blue Ray disks.  Does 16.10 now support it?  I've tried using kb3 but it displays a blank window; I've also tried some command line tools to no avail.

Comment: I haven't tried yet with burning, but I saved this article from a while ago and I keep meaning to try it out sometime.  https://irishjesus.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/blu-ray-movie-authoring-in-linux/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two aspects:

- Formatting Blu-ray content  for entertainment video players.

This is indeed in bad shape, because nobody seems to be masochist enough
to implement UDF 2.5 filesystem production. That's what the article shown 
by Terrance describes.

- Burning data to Blu-ray media.

This is known to work with GUI programs K3B and Xfburn. They can put readily
formatted images onto BD-R and BD-RE media with one or more layer (25, 50,
or 100 GB). They can also produce ISO 9660 filesystems for data storage.

Command line programs which can write to Blu-ray are: growisofs, cdrskin, 
cdrecord, xorriso. Assumed we have the data preformatted in file image.iso:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=image.iso
cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject image.iso
cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject image.iso
xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject image.iso
```

Not suitable is program wodim, even if it runs under the name "cdrecord".

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: Thanks!  I don't really care about formatting for entertainment video players...I'm just worried about making archives and getting old garbage off my hard drives.

Comment: Consider the examples from the end of man 1 xorriso:
"Blank medium and compose a new ISO image as batch run" and
"Incremental backup of a few directory trees". xorriso command
-for_backup, if used as one of the first arguments, records MD5s
of superblock, directory tree, session, and single files.
Command -check_media can later at any time verify that the medium
is still readable and matches the checksums.